# MapboxGL - How to create route line between markers as curves?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, markers

I am trying to add a curve line between markers. I have a set of markers that are linked to specific markers using lines. I need to change that line into curves in Mapbox. Tried with the turf package also, which was not connecting the markers properly.
Either way of the following is ok:

If it is possible to create a source layer in Mapbox studio and use it on our map. (That needs to be curved irrespective of the origin and destination points)

If it is possible to curve the lines, using any of the package available like Turf etc..,

```
var start = turf.point([-122, 48]); 
   var end = turf.point([-77, 39]);
  var greatCircle = turf.greatCircle(start, end, { npoints: 100 });
  arc.push(greatCircle.geometry.coordinates);
  route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Turf function you are looking for is [bezierSpline](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bezierSpline).